# Is there any way to make a BASE URL which applies even if HREFs are "absolute"?

Tags: html, browser, radix

I'm developing a website which will live on `https://www.example.com/`. While developing, and later as a test site, it's at `http://127.0.0.1/temp-dir-for-my-project/`.

This means that I currently have a bunch of hrefs in the HTML, as well as CSS files, starting with `/temp-dir-for-my-project/`, which obviously break once I'm done and upload it to the live site. Over there, it should be `/` instead.

Sadly, the `BASE` element, which I thought would solve this, only applies to *relative* paths. For example, `./meow.html` with `/temp-dir-for-my-project/` as the `BASE` would refer to `/temp-dir-for-my-project/meow.html`, but `/meow.html` in the same situation would be... `/meow.html`, because it's an "absolute" path.

Before you say "just use relative paths, then!", well... If I do that, I have to keep track of in which "dir" I am. For example, for the webpage at `https://www.example.com/test.html`, I could do: `./other.html` and it would work both on the live site and in my test site (assuming the `BASE` is set). But the webpage at `https://www.example.com/subdir/test.html` would have to link to './../other.html' or else it wouldn't link to the correct page.

This gets messy. I wish I could use "absolute" paths and still have the `BASE` be the... base. Is there a way, or am I forced to use `./../../blabla...` for any page located in subdirs (whether those be real subdirs or just how the URL is rewritten to look)?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, or just using HTML? If not a framework, I would use a local vhost like `example.local`, therefore giving the same experience as when you push to production

Comment: @JayHewitt Pure HTML/CSS/etc. A local vhost sounds interesting, but also error-prone. I'm not sure if PHP 8's built-in webserver supports that, and I found it to be a major chore to deal with nginx, not to mention Apache in the past, so I would rather not have to install extra software.

Comment: Can't you just mount your `temp-dir-for-my-project` as the root instead of the parent directory?

Comment: @magicmn I suppose, but then the whole dir structure is messed up where I have a number of "sites" localhost-only for my own use.